# Spring cloud sleuth with spring cloud gateway

Tags: spring-webflux, spring-cloud-gateway, spring-cloud-sleuth, reactor-netty, zipkin

I'm using spring cloud sleuth with spring cloud gateway (webflux based)
I would like to only "log" TraceId and SpanId without propagating  in http request

Given this scenario :

client --> cloud gateway --> target_uri

I dont want to add X-B3-* (and other custom fields) to the http request going towards target uri. I ONLY want to log (for now)
these informations, and I was able to do it without problems.
Is there an option ?
I've to customise something ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can disable the integration between Sleuth and Feign with the property

```
spring.sleuth.feign.enabled = false
```

You can read more about this on the docs from [Sleuth - OpenFeign Integration](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-sleuth/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#sleuth-openfeign-integration).

Bear in mind that Sleuth doesn't have a way to disable the header injection based on an endpoint, so this is an all on / off switch. This is a problem if you have another service and want to send the trace headers to the other service, but not to services outside your control.

#### Edit

Since you are using netty, you have to set this flag:

```
spring.sleuth.web.client.enabled = false
```

There's more info in the [docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-sleuth/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#sleuth-http-client-netty-integration)

Comment: Hi @Augusto, this does not works because in this context (spring cloud gateway, web flux and netty based) is not used Feign to propagate the headers. (is used instead reactor.netty.http.client.Httpclient i saw in the code)

Comment: I've updated the answer. Sleuth uses a different flag for netty.

Comment: thank you very much @Augusto, this seems to have solved. The strange thing is that I had already tried yesterday with this flag and I got that it didn't forward the headers but it didn't even log them! But now it works (it logs them but doesn't forward them in the http request). I will still do some more tests but if the problem is solved I will vote the answer as solved. (and best answer)